# Cloning of an array

Tags: typescript, angular6

I am cloning an array, normal adding functionality is working good. But when I delete some clone and then add a new clone then the last element in the array of clones is **getting cleared in the UI but still existing in the DOM**.

working code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j4ra7u

CURRENT BEHAVIOUR
Consider we have three completely filled clones, and I delete the first clone and then add a new clone. While pushing the new clone into the array, the last filled clone in the array is getting cleared.

But this does not happen when I delete the last filled clone in the array. It works fine.

Comment: Personally, I don't think someone will look at a huge bunch of external code. Better [create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it here.

Comment: I have edited the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying so many workarounds, the code started working as expected **when I removed the Form tag**.

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5xvzn

Please mention if there is any other way without removing the form tag.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the problem you were talking about, but I noticed that when I delete all records, the record that gets automatically added is a copy of the record most recently added before that, instead of blank.  This is because your `newTemplateAdd` method is allowing `this.N_temp` to remain aliased to an element of `this.N_items`, so data entered into the record gets saved in `this.N_temp`, and `removeNewClone` copies `this.N_temp` without reinitializing it.

Instead of doing this funny thing with `this.N_temp`, wouldn't it be simpler to just have a function that creates a new record each time you need one?  See [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eddagv?file=src/app/app.component.ts).